# PHP Curl - Código HTTP

Tags: php, curl

Estoy creando un script en PHP que verifique que el código HTTP regresado por `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` esté dentro de mi matriz (*200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208 y 226*).

Sin embargo, hay algunos sitios que tienen redireccionamientos (*3xx*), y no sé si el código HTTP se va a considerar válido en mi código (no sé que regresa `curl_getinfo()` cuando hay un redireccionamiento, por ejemplo una re-escritura del protocolo HTTP a HTTPS?)

Answer (score 0):

Hay una opción en cURL para seguir redirecciones

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
```

El problema es que en algunos servidores no está activa; si es el caso, puedes intentar la sugerencia de: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036674/alternative-for-curlopt-followlocation-on-shared-server-with-open-basedir-on**

Con esto eliminas la posibilidad de códigos 3xx.

Comment: Vale tio...!!!! Estas guapote